# Get result measurement into a circuit with Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, error-correction

I'm trying to implement the three qubit bit flip code in Qiskit. 
Therefore, I need to get the result of a measure of two ancilla qubits, to deduce which gate I need to use do recover my logical qubit. I know how to get the result of a measure, at the end of a circuit with :

```
backend_sim = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
job_sim = execute(qc, backend_sim, shots=1000)
result_sim = job_sim.result()
counts = result_sim.get_counts(qc)
plot_histogram(counts)
```

But, I don't know how to get the result of a measure into the circuit. Sorry if my question is stupid, I'm a beginner on Qiskit.

[image]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you probably want something like [this](https://qiskit.org/documentation/terra/summary_of_quantum_operations.html#conditional-operations). These gates apply their usual actions if the value in the classical register is a certain value. NOTE: I think they only work in simulators though.

Comment: This circuit before the measurements simplifies a lot. You should do that first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! @MatthewStypulkoski I will try this. I think this will work. But do you know, why we can do these only with simulators ?

Comment: @AHusain why do you mean by "You should do that first" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Circuit Composer, you can use an if statement as shown below The circuit measures qubit 1 after a gate operation and, if it is 0, then applies an X gate to qubit 2:

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[3];
creg c[3];

x q[0];
measure q[0] -> c[0];
if(c==0) x q[1]; # here where you can set it to trigger on c == 1
measure q[1] -> c[1];
```

[image]

This Circuit yields a 1 for q[0] and a 0 for qubit 1 , because the X gate isn't applied due to the conditional. Hope this helps!

Edit: For syntax in qiskit, please look at the code below:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(q, c)
qc.h(q)
qc.measure(q,c)
qc.x(q[0]).c_if(c, 0)
qc.measure(q,c)
qc.draw(output='mpl')
```

It appears that you should use .c_if at the end of a certain operation to use conditionals.

Comment: Firstly thanks for answering my question. This work with Openqasm, but with Qiskit I try after measuring  `meas.measure(q[3],c[0])` to use the variable `c[0]`, and it returns me the variable `ClassicalRegister(2, 'c')`. I didn't found any information about the value of the classical register in this variable.

Comment: @lufydad For the syntax with using qiskit, please look at the "conditional operations" section [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/terra/summary_of_quantum_operations.html)