# How to implement if statement based on measurement results in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, error-correction

I tried to implement three qubit bit flip code in qiskit and need to get the result of measurements and then apply recovery quantum operations conditioned on the measurement results. The following is a simplified version to initialize a circuit:

```
q= QuantumRegister(3)
c= ClassicalRegister(3)
qc= QuantumCircuit(q, c)
qc.measure(q,c)
```

I noticed that [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6462/get-result-measurement-into-a-circuit-with-qiskit) had a similar question and they transformed the statement

```
if(c[0]==0) qc.x(q[0])
```

into

```
qc.x(q[0]).c_if(c[0], 0)
```

However, I want to have multiple quantum operations conditioned on the if statement

```
if c[0]==1 and c[1]==1:
    qc.x(q[0])
    qc.x(q[1])
```

can this work with "c_if"?

Comment: I wonder what these *if's* physically mean. IMO quantum computer consists of qubits, gates that can be applied to qubits, and measurements; there is no external logic to branch a program on a measurement outcome. You can branch a program on a measurement outcome using controlled gates such as `CNOT` and additional qubit(s); is this how *if's* are implemented?

Comment: I agreed. The "c_if" statement seems like a programming language and to implement it physically need controlled gates. I think qiskit provides this logic for simplicity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, what you want can't be run on the hardware right now. See [this github issue](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-textbook/issues/119).

However, you can do this in the simulators. If, for example, `c[0]` and `c[1]` make up a two-bit classical register `c`, you can do this:

```
qc.x(q[0]).c_if(c,3)
qc.x(q[1]).c_if(c,3)
```

Comment: Thank you. Does "c_if(c,3)" mean that both two bits in classical register are equal to 3? Can bits in classical register equal differently, such as "if(c[0]==0 and c[1]==1)"?

Comment: The value of the classical register `c` is interpreted as a number in binary. Thus, `c_if(c,3)` means `c[0]==1` and `c[1]==1`. If you want `c[0]==0` and `c[1]==1`, the condition is `c_if(c,2)`.