# Is it possible to implement c_if statement based on a measurement in a single specified classical bit in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, error-correction

I'm trying to write a 1-bit teleportation error correction code and there is one part in it where I need to add a gate that's dependent on a measurement from earlier in the circuit.  The measurement is stored on a single classical bit, and I'm trying to use `c_if` to apply the gate based on the measurement result of that bit.

Intuitively I would think this could be written as: `qc.h(q[0]).c_if(c[3], 1)` but that only returns an error while `qc.h(q[0]).c_if(c, 1)` gives no error (though it doesn't give the result I'm looking for).  Is there a way to link c_if to a single classical bit instead of the classical register?

[This question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9372/how-to-implement-if-statement-based-on-measurement-results-in-qiskit) is similar and the answer seems to imply that it isn't possible to use c_if this way.

If c_if can't do this, would something like what they mentioned in their question: `if(c[3]==1) qc.h(q[0])` work in qiskit?  For my purposes the operation needs to be integrated into the circuit, so if it does work would the gate be applied automatically?

Answer (score 3):

`c_if` must be used on an entire `ClassicalRegister`. However, it is still possible to use it on a single classical bit. You would need to create a `ClassicalRegister` of size 1, and attach that to your circuit. This would be the register that you input into the `c_if` call.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister

c1 = ClassicalRegister(1)
c3 = ClassicalRegister(3)
q4 = QuantumRegister(4)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q4, c3)  # Instantiate with one of the classical registers 
qc.add_register(c1) # Add the other classical register

qc.x(0)
qc.measure(range(4), range(4)
qc.x(0).c_if(c1, 1)  # Add an X-Gate if the classical register c1 outputs 1
```

Do note though, using `c_if` is not supported on the real hardware, so you would only be able to run this circuit on the simulator.